# nested virtualization with KVM: -enable-kvm in qemu in nested virtualization

Tags: virtualization, qemu, kvm

In my already virtualized host, trying to pass the option the option `-enable-kvm -m 1024`, will fail:

```
qemu-system-x86_64  -vga std -enable-kvm -m 1024   -monitor telnet:localhost:9313,server,nowait -drive file=my_img.img,cache=none
# Could not access KVM kernel module: No such file or directory
# failed to initialize KVM: No such file or directory
```

If I remove that option `-enable-kvm -m 1024`, qemu will load (but it will take forever, because it is using software emulation):

```
qemu-system-x86_64  -vga std  -monitor telnet:localhost:9313,server,nowait -drive file=my_img.img,cache=none
# qemu running, OK, but image taking forever to load.
```

Surely, this virtualized host of mine has capabilities of nesting its own virtualization. Everywhere I find information about it [like here:  https://docs.openstack.org/developer/devstack/guides/devstack-with-nested-kvm.html ] tells me that I must check the file `/sys/module/kvm_intel/parameters/nested` which is simply not available, because `kvm-intel` isn't and can't be loaded from inside an image:

```
sudo modprobe  kvm-intel
# modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'kvm_intel': Operation not supported
```

Probably that method of debugging nested virtualization only works in the bare metal. **So, how do I enable (forward the support of) kvm from inside a kvm?**

Additional info:

```
lscpu # from inside the virtualized host
# Architecture:          x86_64
# ...
# Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
# CPU family:            6
# Model:                 13
# Model name:            QEMU Virtual CPU version (cpu64-rhel6)
# Stepping:              3 
# ...
# Hypervisor vendor:     KVM
```

`ltrace` of qemu:

```
# open64("/dev/kvm", 524290, 00)                   = -1
# __errno_location()                               = 0x7f958673c730
# __fprintf_chk(0x7f957fd81060, 1, 0x7f9586474ce0, 0Could not access KVM kernel module: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To test if the `kvm` support is enabled in the current host (ie, it works in the virtual machine) do:

```
grep -E "(vmx|svm)" /proc/cpuinfo 
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl nonstop_tsc extd_apicid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq monitor ssse3 fma cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt aes xsave avx f16c lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch osvw ibs xop skinit wdt lwp fma4 tce tbm topoext perfctr_core perfctr_nb arat cpb hw_pstate npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save tsc_scale vmcb_clean flushbyasid decodeassists pausefilter pfthreshold vmmcall bmi1
```

In the question:

```
grep -E "(vmx|svm)" /proc/cpuinfo | wc -l 
0
```

It means that the support is disabled, and `enable-kvm` won't work. Action in the bare metal machine is required.

Answer (score 6):

By default, Linux KVM has nested virtualization support disabled.

You have to [enable it in the host](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/using-nested-virtualization-in-kvm/#_enabling_nested_virtualization) of the outermost VM (in your question you tried to do that inside the outermost VM, instead). For example, for an Intel CPU:

```
# rmmod kvm_intel
# modprobe kvm_intel nested=1
```

Verification (on the host of the outermost VM):

```
$ cat /sys/module/kvm_intel/parameters/nested
Y
```

(The KVM module for AMD is unsurprisingly called `kvm_amd`.)

Nesting can be enabled persistently via dropping a config file into `/etc/modprobe.d`.

This is a necessary condition for nested virtualization. In addition to that, you need to [tell QEMU to enable virtualization support](https://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Nested_Guests#How_to_run) in the outermost VM by supplying the right CPU argument, e.g.:

```
-cpu host
```

or something more specific like:

```
-cpu Haswell-noTSX-IBRS,vmx=on
```

Inside the outermost VM, you can verify virtualization support via:

```
$ grep -o 'vmx\|svm' /proc/cpuinfo
$ kvm-ok
INFO: /dev/kvm exists
KVM acceleration can be used
```

Comment: This works for Windows 11 VMs. After a lot of work and troubleshooting with TPM2 and UEFI, I did manage to get Ubuntu running nested inside WSL on a Windows 11 VM with an Ubuntu host system. Setting `-cpu host` is required. To set this in Virtual Machine Manager, override the CPU configuration and select `host-passthrough` as the CPU model.